# Cannot reboot after upgrade to 14.04: CMOS/CPNV checksum Bad

Tags: command-line, nvidia, 14.04, upgrade

I installed on my old desktop (which I use for my work at office) the Ubuntu 12.04. Yesterday I thought I should try upgrading to 14.04 through terminal commands which I found all around the net. Finished downloading, installing and everything and asked me to restart.

Problem is at first I get a black screen stating "CMOS/CPNV checksum Bad". If I get through this through BIOS (don't know how, I just restore optimal), then I face dead end.

I have a white screen with blinking points and nothing works/loads.

I saw around answers with command lines and terminals but I cannot read anything even when I press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

I read about problems/clashes considering the NVIDIA. What can I do?

I am novice. Could someone please walk me through step by step?

Answer (score 1):

> "CMOS/CPNV checksum Bad"

This indicates that there is a hardware problem. You probably need to replace your CMOS battery with a new one. Then enter BIOS (probably key F4 on boot), configure boot order etc., and exit saving changes.

It is possible that there is some other incompatibility between 14.04 and your system, which you can test by downloading and booting the Ubuntu ISO image.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it :

```
# reboot=pci
# reboot=b
# sudo reboot
```

i you see black screen and terminal pls type :

```
# startx
```

I hope it works